# Sequential Search Java Missing Return Statement?

Tags: java, search, return, sequential

I don't understand why I keep getting the error of "missing return statement." Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
//sequential search
public static int seqSearch(int[] items, int goal)throws IOException
{
    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < items.length; c++)
    {
        if (items[c] == goal)     // Searching element is present
            return c;
    }
    if (c == items.length)  // Searching element is absent
        return (-1);
}//end seq
```

Comment: There is a path through your code that never hits a `return` statement. You'll need a `return` statement for that path.

Comment: Because not all possible paths have a return statement, even if the paths that dont, cant happen. In this case you can remove the `if (c == items.length)` to fix this warning. Is it just a warning or error?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question (and I believe that both did), you should mark one answer as correct and the question as closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return something only if `items[c] == goal` inside the loop or `if (c == items.length)`. This means that you return -1 at the last iteration but if you've got that far you've already iterated through the whole array. Replacing

```
if (c == items.length)  // Searching element is absent
        return (-1);
```

with just

```
return (-1);
```

should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Because both your return statements are inside

```
if(...){
return
}
```

So in some scenario your code might "miss" both return statements.
That means if none of those if statements are true, your method won't return anything. Do you need to add an else statement to your last if for example, which returns something.